# Framebuffer over i2c

Tags: raspbian, video, i2c, framebuffer

Is it possible to output a framebuffer over i2c to a ssd1306 or over ic for a screen under raspbian, for example?

Comment: If you can read the framebuffer in software, yes.  But expect it to be slower than a dedicated display interface.

Comment: @ChrisStratton what about fbtft?